# installing python and imports locally on Linux

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, tkinter

I have a linux machine which I do not have administrator access to. I wish to run a python program (locally) that uses TKinter import. How would I got about installing both into userspace so that the gui would run given the command ./{filename}. I have gotten rid of the .py extension and marked it as executable already.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have administrator access to install it, download the tarball, untar and run it in terminal. Download all dependencies and access them in the same shell to execute the required command.